# How to add a column from csv file in to array with framework pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file [thnigs.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4G9.png) which has 2 columns : **thing** and **date**. I need to import data from CSV file in to arrays as below:

**things = [ ]**   **thing** column data from CSV.

**date =[ ]**    **date** column data from CSV.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('things.csv')

things = []
date = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.values`:

```
things = df['things'].values
date = df['date'].values
```